Already using index but query still slow in Mariadb
here's my query :
select
                    sum(dnpi_qty * ((so_item_qty - so_item_delivered_qty) / so_item_qty))
            from

                            (select stock_qty as dnpi_qty, qty as so_item_qty,
                                    delivered_qty as so_item_delivered_qty, so_item.parent, so_item.name
                            from `tabSales Order Item` so_item USE INDEX (item_code_warehouse_delivered_by_supplier_qty_delivered)
                            where item_code = 'BA-0' and warehouse = 'W1'
                            and so_item.delivered_by_supplier = 0
                            and so_item.qty > so_item.delivered_qty
                            and exists (select name from `tabSales Order` so where so.name=so_item.parent
                                    and so.docstatus = 1
                                    and so.status in ('On Hold','To Deliver','To Deliver and Bill')
                            )
                    ) tab
            where
                    so_item_qty >= so_item_delivered_qty;

query time is still slow around 10 sec, rows return is 5k+ records
Explained query:
explained_img
explained_img
Table indexes:
Sales Order Item indexes
[SHOW CREATE TABLE]
CREATE TABLE `tabSales Order Item` (
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `creation` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified_by` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `owner` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `docstatus` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `parent` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `parentfield` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,`item_code` varchar(140) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,item_name` varchar(350) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `base_net_amount` decimal(18,6) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.000000,
  `net_rate` decimal(18,6) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.000000,
  `stock_uom` varchar(140) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `base_price_list_rate` decimal(18,6) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.000000,
  `warehouse` varchar(140) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,`delivered_qty` decimal(18,6) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.000000,
  `price_list_rate` decimal(18,6) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.000000,
  `transaction_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `item_group` varchar(140) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `planned_qty` decimal(18,6) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.000000,
  `amount` decimal(18,6) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.000000,
  `customer_item_code` varchar(140) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `net_amount` decimal(18,6) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.000000,
  `returned_qty` decimal(18,6) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.000000,
  `target_warehouse` varchar(140) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `ordered_qty` decimal(18,6) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.000000,
  `supplier` varchar(140) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `delivered_by_supplier` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,PRIMARY KEY (`name`),
  KEY `prevdoc_docname` (`prevdoc_docname`),
  KEY `parent` (`parent`),
  KEY `modified` (`modified`),
  KEY `item_code_warehouse_delivered_by_supplier` (`item_code`,`warehouse`,`delivered_by_supplier`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED 

[MariaDB Version]
10.4.14-MariaDB-1:10.4.14+maria~bionic-log
I've tried to use join instead of subquery but the result was similar
Please any suggestions to improve this query?

can you include show create table .. to describe indexes and the explain info as text. Which MariaDB version? Edit question with these details. Do you really want 5k+ records returned?

Using MariaDB 15.1

"edit the question" rather than adding comments. 15.1 is the client version - look at select version() for the server version.

MariaDB version -> 10.4.14-MariaDB-1:10.4.14+maria~bionic-log

delivered_by_supplier is NOT NULL, so remove the coalesce and just do and so_item.delivered_by_supplier=0.  add qty and delivered_qty to the multicolumn index (at the end).

hi @ysth I followed your suggestion and updated in the question. explicitly USE INDEX but still got slow 10 sec query.

if you just do select count(*) from (select stock_qty...) is that 10 seconds?  how many does it return?  what does the explain look like with the changes?
